# Encode audio to AAC or MP3 with an AudioUnit (CoreAudio) possible?

Tags: ios, macos, core-audio

Is it possible to encode audio data to a compressed format like MP3 or AAC by using a CoreAudio AudioUnit? If yes, which AudioUnit (type/subtype) does the job? How do I configure it (to not get a `kAudioUnitErr_FormatNotSupported` error, when trying to use anything else than PCM)?

Answer (score 2):

You can you core audio to encode to most audio data types. Mp3 is not one of them.

Here is a complete list of what you can use.
[Encoding file types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/AudioFileConvertRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/AudioFileTypeID)

When using these file types you will still need to create AudioStreamBasicDescribtions. I've never found a comprehensive list of them all but google searches provide ones that work for the most common ones such as caf, aac, mp4 and wav.

To actually write the files to disk you would create an ExtAudioFileRef and use ExtAudioFileWriteAsync to create the file on disk.

You shouldnt need to use an actual audio unit for converting if your just taking samples from a remoteio callback.

I've used this before to convert from mp3 to wav. Also from mp3 to wav to aac.(note I dont think you can convert from one compressed format to another. It has to be from pcm to a format)

Hope that helps.

Comment: This page should be a list describing all the supporting codec
Audio Data Format Identifiers
https://developer.apple.com/reference/coreaudio/1572096-audio_data_format_identifiers?language=objc